# Как работает bearer атвторизация в Yii2

Tags: yii2, api, rest, auth

Мне важен принцип работы, а то я что-то не понимаю. Никаких гайдов по тому как настроить именно bearer авторизации нет, даже в документации. Мне бы просто по шагам кто-нить объяснил бы, или по листинг кода, в общем был бы очень благодарен любой помощи.

Comment: Это потому что по дефолту ее нет. Только ставить дополнительно что-то для этого.

Comment: В поисковиках забанили? Ладно, поищу за вас http://developer.uz/blog/yii2-rest-authentication-and-authorization/, http://web-andryshka.ru/yii2-rest-avtorizacia/

Comment: @ArchDemon я конечно дико извиняюсь, эти ссылки я посещал задолго до того как решил здесь спросить, мне нужен принцип работы. Есть догадки, кажется что нужен логин и пароль после при валидации сгенерировать токен с опрделенной временной меткой, мне просто нужно узнать как сие работает, куда и как передавать токен и метку, чтоб запрос получил доступ.

Comment: Я бегло пробежал по тем страницам, там всё расписано.

Comment: @ArchDemon http://web-andryshka.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/yii2-bearer-auth.png Эта картинка, единственная полезная информация относительно вопроса. Но спасибо)